# Bi-directional URL rewrting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, translation

I'd like to add a 'simple' translatable framework on my php website. I have french and english languages and perhaps more in the future.

I can easily redirect to a different language from .htaccess with these rules :

```
RewriteRule ^Abonnement$ php/vigneron/inscription.php?la=fr [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Register$ php/vigneron/inscription.php?la=en [L,QSA]
```

My problem is : if I don't want to build an array in php linking Abonnement (french page) to Register (easy :) english page), I have to put the ugly URL : php/vigneron/inscription.php?la=XX in my language selection box and this URL is visible in browser's address bar

So my question is : is there a way in .htaccess to link php/vigneron/inscription.php?la=en to Register ?
Did I miss something in my .htaccess lines ?
My fear is to make a infinite loop from clean URL to real path file.

Second question very closed to the first : the pages are still available with long URL : php/vigneron/inscription.php?la=en, is there a way to prevent this and force the browser via .htaccess to display clean URL ?

Thanks for your observations and remarks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`So my question is : is there a way in .htaccess to link php/vigneron/inscription.php?la=en to Register ?`

Yes sure it can be done. use these rules for that purpose:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+php/vigneron/inscription\.php\?la=en[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /register? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+php/vigneron/inscription\.php\?la=fr[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Abonnement? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you except saying you're the .htaccess killer ! To try to understand the logic of this rule : does it means the "[&\s]" will pass all other aguments and the "^[A-Z]{3,}\s/" handle the www + domaine name ?

Comment: You're welcome. `[A-Z]{3,}` means request method for ex. GET, POST, PUT etc. And `[&\s]` will match a space or `&`. Which means parameter `la=en` is either last parameter or has some more parameters following it.